# Rails 5 beta bundle update has gem conflict

Tags: bundler, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to update Rails to 5.0.0.beta1, and I get errors that look like this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "minitest":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.0.0.beta1, which depends on
      activejob (= 5.0.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.0.0.beta1, which depends on
activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.0.0.beta1, which depends
on minitest (~> 5.1)
    minitest-rails-capybara was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      minitest-rails was resolved to 0.5, which depends on
        minitest (~> 4.0)
```

No gem, including `minitest-rails-capybara`, has its version set explicitly in my Gemfile. There is no `Gemfile.lock` file in my app (I removed the existing one in the upgrade branch.)

`minitest-rails-capybara` is the latest version in the current gemset (and in others.) Why am I getting this error?

**EDIT** Even after starting with a new app, (`rails new`) if I add these lines to the Gemfile, I get the above errors:

```
group :test do
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
end
```

Versions:

- Ruby: 2.3.0
- Bundler: 1.11.2
- gem: 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I'm jumping the gun somewhat here - those gems at least don't have their Rails5-compatible versions on Rubygems.org.

Pointing directly to Github fixes this:

```
  gem 'minitest-rails',  git: 'https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails', branch: 'rails5'
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara', git: 'https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara', branch: 'rails5'
```